# Highcharts irregular density on xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart which consists of irregular values on x Axis. There is much more values around `14` than between `0` and `2`, thus it is being rendered like below to keep interval between subsequent points equal:

[image]

My goal is to keep the grid on x Axis equally distributed even if the distribution of points is irregular. So I would like the labels to be `0,3,6,9,12,15`. Tried with `gapSize` and `tickInterval` parameters but highcharts still keep trying to auto distribute the points.

Is there any solution to enforce such distribution?

My config:

```
 xAxis: {
    title: ...,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    crosshair: ...,
    labels: {
    format: "{value:.0f}",
    y: 12
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mickl, Are you using Highstock? If so, the `ordinal` option is enabled by default: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal If not, please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gfoxn3t/ as a base to start.

Comment: @ppotaczek yes, ordinal fixes it, can you please reply so that I can upvote and accept your anser? Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ordinal` option is enabled by default for an x-axis when using Highstock. You need to disable it to avoid the issue.

```
  xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y7vf1bzu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal